# Python PyAutoGui keypress crashes in separate thread on mac

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, tkinter, pyautogui

I'm running into an issue running a keypress with PyAutoGui in a separate thread on a mac.
Here's the error I get:

```
Python[39499:497432] pid(39499)/euid(501) is calling TIS/TSM in non-main thread environment, ERROR : This is NOT allowed. Please call TIS/TSM in main thread!!!
```

Like the message says, it works fine when I run it in the main thread. But I would prefer to do the action in a separate thread so it doesn't block UI. Is there a way to get around this? It looks to be working fine on a windows machine.

Info

- Python: 3.8.3
- OS: Mac MoJave 10.14.6
- TkInter: 8.5

To reproduce, run the following code and click the `Start` button in the window that pops up.

```py
import threading

import pyautogui

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def press_key():
    pyautogui.press('a')


def handle_button_press():
    t = threading.Thread(target=press_key)
    t.start()    


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Crash')

    content = ttk.Frame(root, width=200, height=200)

    button = tk.Button(content, text='Start', command=handle_button_press)

    # Layout 
    content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))
    button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))

    content.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    content.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve it is to use a Process.

It's not a thread-solution, but it works and its not going to block the main thread.

Here's the code slightly modified.

```py
import multiprocessing

import pyautogui

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time


def press_key():
    pyautogui.press('a')


def handle_button_press():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=press_key)
    p.start()    


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title('Crash')

    content = ttk.Frame(root, width=200, height=200)

    button = tk.Button(content, text='Start', command=handle_button_press)

    # Layout 
    content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))
    button.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(tk.N, tk.E, tk.S, tk.W))

    content.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    content.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```